# Alernatives to Core Data and iCloud?

Tags: iphone, ios, database, core-data, icloud

Core Data and iCloud has a terrible reputation, just googling anything related to it reveals pages of rants about how difficult it is to work with. I'm thus looking for an alternative for data sync between iOS apps. This can be an alternative to traditional core data syncing with iCloud, a different online service, a different storage type. Anything that'll mean I don't have to continue with iCloud and Core Data as it is right now.

Comment: Well. Good luck to you. And I mean that sincerely. It won't be easy to get Apple to agree to distribute an app that doesn't use their own services. Especially since you want to sync devices. Could be tricky. :)

Comment: If you don't mind users having to create accounts, DropBox is a good choice. There are several 3rd party services with ios APIs you can use, but they're typically not free. I wouldn't worry about Apple approval - there is no requirement to use iCloud. iCloud is worthless if you want to sync data to Android devices too.

Comment: I ran into the same complaints when iCloud was introduced and wanted to stay away until the technology matured.  I ended up using Dropbox to store the data files and it has worked out well, but 'rolling your own' has downsides as well.  It won't be as user friendly or 'automatic' as iCloud would be (most likely).